# Assigning number to users microsoft teams

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, microsoft-teams, call-queue

```
$credential = Get-Credential 
Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $credential
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $credential
Connect-MsolService -Credential $credential
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/user"

#---------------------------------Call queue
$Util2 = Get-PnPListItem -List "2"

foreach ($temp2 in $Util2) {

$CQNom = $temp2['CQ_nom']
$CQMail = $temp2['CQ_Compte_de_ressource']
$CQNum = $temp2['Tel_sda']    


# Your config
$cqName = $CQNom
# Create resource account of call queue type
$cqRaParams = @{
    UserPrincipalName = $CQMail
    # ID taken from cmdlet documentation
    ApplicationId     = '11cd3e2e-fccb-42ad-ad00-878b93575e07'
    DisplayName       = "RA_$cqName"
}
$newCqRa = New-CsOnlineApplicationInstance @cqRaParams

$User = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $newCqRa.ObjectId
Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId $User.ObjectId -UsageLocation US
$License = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicense

$License.SkuId = "440eaaa8-b3e0-484b-a8be-62870b9ba70a"
$LicensesToAssign = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicenses
$LicensesToAssign.AddLicenses = $License
Set-AzureADUserLicense -ObjectId $User.ObjectId -AssignedLicenses $LicensesToAssign

Set-CsOnlineApplicationInstance -Identity $newCqRa.ObjectId -OnpremPHONENUMBER $CQNum }
```

I have a problem with my program. I am creating a call queue for several users who are stored in a Sharepoint list. At the point where I have to assign them phone numbers it shows me an error. Someone can help me ?

```
The application endpoint was not found in Active Directory.
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-CsOnlineApplicationInstance], ApplicationInstanceManagementException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Hosted.PlatformService.ApplicationInstance.ApplicationInstanceManagementException,Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Hosted.PlatformService.ApplicationInstance.SetCsOnlineApplicationInstanceCmdlet
+ PSComputerName        : api.interfaces.records.teams.microsoft.com
```

A note: when I run this program on a single user it works normally.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnZ2o.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKsb3.png)

Comment: The application endpoint was not found in Active Directory.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-CsOnlineApplicationInstance], ApplicationInstanceManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Hosted.PlatformService.ApplicationInstance.ApplicationInstanceManagementException,Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Hosted.PlatformService.ApplicationInstance.SetCsOnli 
   neApplicationInstanceCmdlet
    + PSComputerName        : api.interfaces.records.teams.microsoft.com

Comment: @Abdouramane -  Can you please pass the ApplicationId in the Set-CsOnlineApplicationInstance and see if that helps. Giving a reference that might help [Set-CsOnlineApplicationInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/skype/set-csonlineapplicationinstance?view=skype-ps)

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT - I have already tried this approach.
A note: when I run this program on a single user it works normally.

Comment: @Abdouramane - Since you said its working for a single user could you please check if you are using the correct ID in `$newCqRa.ObjectId` while looping through the list?          
Also please check if you are using the following id for the app id while creating a call queue  
`Set-CsOnlineApplicationInstance -Identity appinstance01@contoso.com -OnpremPhoneNumber +14250000000 -ApplicationId 11cd3e2e-fccb-42ad-ad00-878b93575e07-DisplayName "AppInstance01"`

Comment: @Abdouramane - Could  you please confirm if you are still facing this issue?

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT - Hi, sorry for the delay. No unfortunately I could not find a way out. I followed your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just checked it at our end and we were able to assign the phone numbers to the users. Can you just try with the following command to update the user details.

```
$personList = @{upn='sip:uset1@contoso.com';phoneNumber='tel:+14250000000'},@{upn='sip:uset2@contoso.com';phoneNumber='tel:+14250000001'}

Foreach($item in $personList)
{
Set-CsUser -Identity $item.upn  -EnterpriseVoiceEnabled $true -HostedVoiceMail $true -OnPremLineURI $item.phoneNumber
}
```